# Как организовать правильные названия SVG спрайтов в gulp?

Tags: svg, gulp, svg-спрайт, спрайт

Использую [gulp-svg-sprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprite).
Как организовать такое в gulp?

Есть папки с файлами

```
folder-icons/
-- icon1.svg
-- icon2.svg
-- icon3.svg

folder-social/
-- social1.svg
-- social2.svg
-- social3.svg
```

На выходе хочу получить

```
folder-icons-sprite.svg
folder-social-sprite.svg
```

Для каждой папки писать задачу в gulp, как то не комильфо.